# Ionic: Background mode does not work in Android 12 with API level 31

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, audio-player, ionic5, background-mode

I have an Ionic 5 app with Audio player which allows user's to play audio even if the app is in background using [Ionic Background mode plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/native/background-mode).

Above requirement works fine in API level 30. But after using API level 31, Ionic Background mode plugin doesn't work in Android 12.

Can any one please suggest me to solve this issue.

Comment: Does it have same issue on emulator and real device as well?

Comment: @StefaniTotokotsopoulou I am getting this issue in real devices.

Comment: What about in emulator ?

Comment: Any luck with background upload? I think background in general is now defunct > API 31?

Comment: @Grant You can check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since background mode is not working for Android 12 with API level 31 for now, I have solved this issue by using `powerOptimization.RequestOptimizations()` before enabling Background mode.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this issue on the plugin repo: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues/576

The problem with Android 12+ was solved by the author with just a few code changes. You can reinstall the `cordova-plugin-background-mode` plugin from the fork: https://github.com/alindzon/cordova-plugin-background-mode